# adding and subtracting a long int binary number in c

Tags: c, math

I have a long int number which is in binary form.

I want to subtract or add another binary number from this number keeping the data type of destination variable same, i.e long int

How can I do it?

I had a solution in which destination variable was an array of int.

what I tried so far

```
int main() {
    long int binary1;
    long int binary2 = 0001;
    int i = 0, rem = 0;
    int sum[20];
    printf("Enter binary number");
    scanf("%ld", &binary1);

    while (binary1 != 0 || binary2 != 0) {
        sum[i++] =(binary1 % 10 + binary2 % 10 + rem) % 2;
        rem =(binary1 % 10 + binary2 % 10 + rem) / 2;
        binary1 = binary1 / 10;
        binary2 = binary2 / 10;
    }


    if (rem != 0)
        sum[i++] = rem;
    --i;


    printf("Sum of two binary numbers: ");

    while (i >= 0)
        printf("%d", sum[i--]);

    return 0;
}
```

Here the result is stored as int. I want to store it in long int because I need to use this sum for the next addition operation.

How can I do the next addition operation where `sum` is one of the operand? `sum` here is in int, and another operand is in long int.

Comment: Post the code that you have tried so we can see where you've gone wrong. Nobody will just give you an implementation.

Comment: Are there any integer variables that are not in binary form?

Comment: Show us *your* code that produces (a) your "long int number which is in binary form", (b) your "binary number" you wish to subtract or add, (c) your expected output, (d) your actual output.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. All numbers are stored in binary form.

Comment: If you overflow, then you overflow. The implementation can't contain such a number in a `long int`. You should stick to whatever big number implementation you had.

Comment: If you are trying to store a `long int` in an *array of `int`* then please post the code to explain.

Comment: @DeiDei Added the code

Comment: @WeatherVane I need to do series of addition, i.e the sum of first two binary number will go into next addition operation. And this sum of first two numbers is stored as an int array.

Comment: @nirvair Code looks OK.  What is the problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do that you cannot do with `long int binary3 = binary2 + binary1;`

Comment: @WeatherVane If I try to add 1011 + 0001, the result will be 1012.

Comment: @chux The problem is I need to use `sum` for the next addition operation. `sum` will be operand for the next operation.

Comment: OK, then use `sum` for the next addition.  Rather than describe what you want, describe what is the problem.

Comment: @chux How would I add the next two binary numbers when one is in int and another in long int?

Comment: @nirvair Your present code appears to add 2 integers just fine per your "binary form".  How is that a problem to do again?

Answer (score 1):

Store as chars it what you want to do I think

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  long int binary1;
  long int binary2 = 0001;
  int i = 0, rem = 0;
  char sum[20];
  printf("Enter binary number: ");
  scanf("%ld", &binary1);

  while (binary1 != 0 || binary2 != 0) {
    sum[i++]=(binary1 % 10 + binary2 % 10 + rem) % 2 > 0 ? '1' : '0';
    rem =(binary1 % 10 + binary2 % 10 + rem) / 2;
    binary1 = binary1 / 10;
    binary2 = binary2 / 10;
  }

  if (rem != 0)
    sum[i++] = rem;
  --i;

  printf("Sum of two binary numbers: ");

  while (i >= 0)
    printf("%c", sum[i--]);

  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that

```
long int binary1=1011;
```

will load your variable with `1011 dec` which is `1111110011 bin` you can use standard addition operator but different load/print operations. If you want to stick to your **DCB** (decimal coded binary) encoding (similar to **BCD** binary coded decimal) then you need to rewrite all math operation. I think simpler would be this:

```
long int bin2dec(long int bin) // DCB -> binary
 {
 long int x,m;
 for (m=1;m<bin;m*=10);
 for (x=0;m;m/=10)
  {
  x<<=1;
  x+=bin/m;
  bin%=m;
  }
 return x;
 }

long int dec2bin(long int dec) // binary -> DCB
 {
 long int x,m;
 for (m=1;m<dec;m<<=1);
 for (x=0;m;m>>=1)
  {
  x*=10;
  x+=dec/m;
  dec&=m-1;
  }
 return x;
 }

void main()
 {
 long int b1=1011;
 long int b2=   1;
 long int b3= 100;
 long int sum;
 sum = dec2bin(bin2dec(b1)+bin2dec(b2)+bin2dec(b3));
 // here print the sum or whatever
 }
```

The point is to convert **DCB** into standard binary representation before math operations and then convert the result back to **DCB** for printing.